# Share apps across multiple Linux distributions?

Tags: command-line, filesystems

I have a triple boot of Ubuntu, Haze OS, and Kali Linux, and I would like to run an app installed on another operating system from my Primary OS. Like running chrome installed in Ubuntu while using Haze OS.

Is this possible? And how can I do this if it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather simple to do something like this using the chroot tool. If you mount say Ubuntu to some location, then you can run the programs from that OS. The process would look something like this.

```
mount /dev/sdu1 /mnt/otheros #Mount the / of the foreign OS to some directory
chroot /mnt/otheros #You should now be able to run all the programs of the foreign OS.
cat /etc/*-release
```

Note: chroot can only be run as root. You may want to look into fakechroot/fakeroot as an alternative.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Worked for me, I do think I might have used it, but didn't know what the tool did. Thanks though, I'm able to access all pentesting apps from kali on all the other OS's